# Is it possible to edit the InsertItems of an item

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have managed to get a list of items that use a specific template. I now want to add an `Insert option` to each of those items.

I understand that I can edit the template `Insert options` and update the `Items` but this will remove some custom `Insert options` that have been added to items. I've looked at the examples [here](https://gist.github.com/Adamsimsy/30dc60df837c1400e6fccd814b3dc752) but there isn't one to do what I need to do - so perhaps it's not possible.

Comment: Do you mean adding Insert options to an existing (inherited) list of Insert options on a template's `__Standard values`?

Comment: I have a content page that someone has removed the inherited `InsertOptions` from and added some different ones. This is why I can't just edit the template `standardvalues` and reset the content `InsertOptions`

Comment: Typically, it's best to manage the Insert options at the template level, even if that means creating multiple types of pages.

Comment: @DanSinclair yes I believe so - I think this might be what we need to do rather than what my question is asking which is sounding more and more like a hack now that I'm beginning to delve deeper into Sitecore.

Comment: Check my answer below for an alternative answer, but I still recommend managing them on the templates' standard values if possible. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Use rules engine to add or remove Insert options

If you can't reset the items' insert options fields for whatever reason, you can always use the `Insert rules` to add or remove insert options with the rules engine.

**Note: the best approach for managing insert options is almost *always* to use the `Insert options` (`__Masters`) field on the `__Standard values` item of the templates. Adding or removing a large number of insert options in this way will affect performance of the Sitecore Content Editor.**

To add a rule that manipulates the insert options:

1. Create a new item of template **Insert Options Rule** below `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Insert Options/Rules`
2. In the **Rule** field, click **Edit Rule** to open the **Rule Set Editor**

   [image: Rule Set Editor]
3. In the **Item Information** section of the conditions list (the left list), click on the condition `where the item template is _specific template_`
4. In the **Rule description** section below, you should see your new rule appear. Click the `specific template` link and select your page's template
5. In the actions list (the right list), click on either `add specific insert options` or `remove specific insert option`
6. In the **Rule description** section, click the `specific` link and select the template you'd like to add/remove

   [image: Rule description configured]
7. Click **OK**
8. Add a name for your rule in the **Name** field
9. Save the rule item

Answer (score 5):

The best option is usually to assign insert options to *standard values* of your base template but if that is not an option, you can try something like:

```
$insertOptionToAdd = '{961227F1-2AC1-4346-B833-D9DBED0B7113}'
$items = Get-Item -Path master: -Query "/sitecore/content/Home/MyItems/* @@templatename ='My Template']"

$items | ForEach-Object {    

  $insertOptions = {$_["__Masters"].Split('|')}.Invoke()

  if ($insertOptions[0] -eq "") {
      $insertOptions.RemoveAt(0);
  }

  if (!$insertOptions.Contains($insertOptionToAdd)) {
      $insertOptions.Add($insertOptionToAdd)

      $newInsertOptions = [string]::Join("|",$insertOptions)
      Write-Host "Updating Insert Options of " $_.ID " to:" $newInsertOptions

      $_.Editing.BeginEdit();
      $_["__Masters"] = $newInsertOptions;
      $_.Editing.EndEdit();
  }
}
```

(Backup your database before running)

Comment: Yes I believe the `standardvalues` approach is the correct way but this project seems to have gone non standard which is unfortunate as I'm completely new to Sitecore

Comment: I would say Rule Engine is your best option here.

Comment: Hi, where is that Invoke method from? I am new to Sitecore Powershell Extension and not sure what that does...

Comment: It's standard Poweshell:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.invoke?view=pscore-6.2.0#System_Management_Automation_PowerShell_Invoke